# Wordpress myCRED Points system

Tags: wordpress, plugins, points

So I have this idea, i want to reward users by points for answering to surveys, opinions, and also for adding new membres to the website.
I tried using myCRED 
http://www.buddyboss.com/mycred-points-management-system-buddypress-plugin-review/
But I don't want it to be based on the commenting system, i want the user to go to a survey page choose an opinion and give answer it, after this he will be rewarded.
I tried searching for plugins but i didn't find any.

So any suggestions for which plugin should i install, or what should i do to make this work.
Thank you guys.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: well i couldn't think of any thing yet, that's why i came to you guys asking for help.